# Why does the source-maps flag effect the code coverage report in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

When I run this command `ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --source-map=false --code-coverage=true --watch=true`, I note that my tests return the following code-coverage summary:

***Code Coverage Without Source Maps - Numbers seem right.***

[image]

However, the code coverage as it appears in my `coverage/` directory has some nonsensical highlighting going on. See these examples:

***Example 1 Without Source Maps - Highlighting seems wrong. (Only pieces of lines listed as untested?)***

[image]

***Example 2 Without Source Maps - Highlighting seems wrong. (Only pieces of lines listed as untested?)***

[image]

Now, when I run the following command, `ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --source-map=true --code-coverage=true --watch=true` (NOTE: THE ONLY CHANGE IS THE SOURCE MAP VALUE), I get incorrect code coverage numbers but the highlighting is fixed. See below.

***Code Coverage With Source Maps - Numbers seem off.***

[image]

***Example 1 With Source Maps - Highlighting seems right.***

[image]

***Example 2 With Source Maps - Highlighting seems right.***

[image]

There are other abnormalities that appear while using source maps too, like my test suite registering that it `Executed 37 of 35` tests successfully.

Why does using Source Maps cause this much of a difference in my code coverage? Shouldn't the numbers and statistics be the same whether I am using Source Maps or not? Similarly, shouldn't the same lines be highlighted exactly the same way whether I'm using Source Maps or not?

***Why the discrepancy?***

Comment: I discovered your question today because I found that your issue also occurs in Angular 8.2.14.

Comment: @knight did u get any solution?

Comment: I hope somebody could give an exlanation why this happens. I'm also getting this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that uncovered lines don't make sense to you - because you don't have source map thus karma run's on minified (since it's default behavior of Angular AOT usually) files - and then as it run on minified it cannot correctly match source code with report coverage.

Solution would be to run `ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage=true --watch=true`